# JSF2.0 component binding at run time

Tags: jsf-2, el

I want to create a JSF2.0 applicaton where in I will know the property value at run time.

how to code the

```
<h:inputText value = "#{dynamic selection}" />
```

I will get the binding value from database during run time is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You could use the brace notation to access the property:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean[myProperty]}" />
```

See more example and explantation in the [EL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (under *Brace notation*).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the properties' values of your EJB Entity mapped in your database and injected in your managed bean, at run time by :

```
<h:inputText value="#{yourBean.yourEJBEntity.yourProperty}" />
```